# Display other user's webform submissions

Tags: hooks, webforms

So, I'm currently programming a module and one of the functions should be that certain users that belong to a specific user group (e. g., 'Counselor') have access to their clients' webform submissions that they made througout the module (which consists of a therapy based program).

First, my intention was to retrieve the webform submission data like so:

```
$myUserId = 80;
$myWebformId = 'my_webform_id';
    
$myWebformSubmissions = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
   ->getStorage('webform_submission')
   ->loadByProperties(['webform_id' => $myWebformId, 'uid' => $myUserId]);

   foreach ($myWebformSubmissions as $myWebformSubmission) {
      $myWebformData = $myWebformSubmission->getData();
    }
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't successful with this approach as I couldn't retrieve any submission data. However, I was then wondering if there is a **specific hook** I could use in order to alter the user id which is used when I access a webform page? More specifically, is it possible for specific user groups to open the webform page but instead of being presented with their own data submissions they will see their clients' submissions instead? That is, one at a time (based on their user id), not all submissions of all their clients altogether.

Any thoughts on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to build a View with exposed filters for webform id and user id?